# Rational Expression Question. (Word problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Joe got a mark of $\dfrac{44}{50}$ on one test and $\dfrac{32}{x}$ on another test. If the average mark on the two tests was 80%, what value was the second test out of?

My revised attempt:

Still confused, is this correct? Seems odd that the answer I am getting is a repeating decimal:

$$\dfrac 12 \left(\dfrac{44}{50}+\dfrac{32}{x}\right)=.8$$

$$\dfrac{44}{50}+\dfrac{32}{x}=\dfrac{.8}{.5}$$

$$\dfrac{32}{x}=\bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}-\dfrac{44}{50}\bigg)x$$

$$32=\dfrac{8}{5}x-\dfrac{44}{50}x$$

$$50\bigg(32=\dfrac{8}{5}x-\dfrac{44}{50}x\bigg)$$

$$1600=80x-44x$$

$$\dfrac{1600}{36} = \dfrac{36x}{36}$$

$$\boxed{x=44.4}$$

Comment: There are unfortunately two possible interpretations of average mark. Some teachers would think of the average as $\frac{44+32}{50+x}$.

Comment: Though you did make the mistake of forgetting to divide by 2 in getting the average (bet you won't do that again!), it is good that you recognized that your answer was wrong and you asked for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unfortunately two possible interpretations of "average mark." Some teachers would think of the average mark as $\frac{44+32}{50+x}$. Essentially they would be computing a weighted average. In that case, solving $\frac{44+32}{50+x}=0.8$, we get $x=45$.

It is quite possible that this is the intended solution, for the alternative $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{44}{50}+\frac{32}{x}\right)=0.8$ does not yield a nice $x$.

Comment: Is my revised solution then the "not nice x" which you are referring to??

Comment: Well, I have not seen any tests that were out of $44.4444\dots$. That is one reason why I think the "add up all the marks and divide by the total maximum possible scores" interpretation may be the intended one. And some teachers really do compute grades that way.

Answer (score 3):

The average is half the sum.  So your first should be $\dfrac 12 \left(\dfrac{44}{50}+\dfrac{32}{x}\right)=.8$